# Turn code to if-else - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

jquery

```
$(function() {                       
  $(".i-icon").click(function() {  
    $("#navBar .navBarInfo li ul").toggle();     
  });
});



$(function() {                       
  $(".menu-icon").click(function() {  
    $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").toggle();     
  });
});
```

html

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div class="navBarStyles">
        <ul class="navBarInfo">
            <li><div class="i-icon iconStyles">u</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="mainNavBar">
            <li><div class="menu-icon iconStyles">z</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6fN/1/)

This must be pretty simple for you guys, but I'm not able to make it work, I need to turn jquery code to if-else statement, to display only one drop down list at a time. For example when I click the u button, it should display the list then when I click on the `z` button, it should hide the  `u` list and display the `z` list.

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: He wants one to close if the other one is clicked.  I did this already though, check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/68nxq/

Comment: _"when I click the u button"_ - As an aside, you describe your "u" and "z" elements as buttons, but they are _not_ buttons or links, so are not accessible via the keyboard. Which means your page will be unusable for anybody who is physically unable to (or simply chooses not to) use a mouse or other pointing device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide the other menu(s) after opening the appropriate one. Therefore, you'll only ever have one open. No if/else needed. Add the following:

```
$("#navBar .otherNavBar li ul").hide();
```

Like so:

```
$(function() {                       
  $(".i-icon").click(function() {  
      $("#navBar .navBarInfo li ul").toggle();
      $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").hide(); // Here
  });
});

$(function() {                       
  $(".menu-icon").click(function() {  
    $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").toggle();  
    $("#navBar .navBarInfo li ul").hide(); // And here
  });
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgPsh/).

Answer (score 3):

Add hide function before it like..

```
$(function() {                       
  $(".i-icon").click(function() {  
      $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").hide();     
    $("#navBar .navBarInfo li ul").toggle();     
  });
});

$(function() {                       
  $(".menu-icon").click(function() {  
      $("#navBar .navBarInfo li ul").hide(); 
    $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").toggle();     
  });
});
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6fN/3/)

Answer (score 1):

**Use only one click event to toggle two list**

jQuery code

```
$(function() {     

      $(".iconStyles").click(function() {  
        $(".iconStyles").next().hide();     
        $(this).next().show();     
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your html mark-up this way

```
<div id="navBar">
<div class="navBarStyles">
    <ul class="navBarInfo">
        <li><div class="i-icon iconStyles">u</div>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mainNavBar">
        <li><div class="menu-icon iconStyles">z</div>
            <ul  class="list">
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and your  jquery can be as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {                       
  $(".iconStyles").click(function() {  
    $('.list').slideUp();
    $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').slideToggle();     
  });
});     
    });
```

the css will remain same.